# keyup event is not listened in form inside django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am using javascript and django for the first time. In my form, I need to show basic amount from the calculation of two field i.e quantity and rate. For that I did the following

```
{% block content %}
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <h1 class="text-center"> Purchase Order</h1>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <!-- {%include 'includes/form.html'%} -->
    {%include 'dashboard/purchase_order/purchase_order_form.html'%}
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('dom is ready');
      $('#form-change').keyup(function() {
        console.log('form')
        var quantity = document.getElementById('id_quantity').value;
        var rate = document.getElementById('id_rate').value;
        if (quantity && rate) {
          document.getElementById('id_basic_amount').value = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(rate);
        }
      })
    })
  </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}


<form id="demo-form2 form-change" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input type="number" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="" id="id_quantity">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input type="number" name="rate" value="0.0" step="0.01" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="" id="id_rate">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <input type="number" name="basic_amount" value="0.0" step="0.01" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="" id="id_basic_amount">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

but the keyup event is not listened. The line `console.log('dom is ready')` is shown in the console but the line `console.log('form')` is not consoled in the console. I tried separate javascript in jsbin and there it is working

http://jsbin.com/hadafezeqa/edit?html,console,output

why it is not working in django template only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the keyup event to one of the form elements, not the form itself.
Try changing the input of the form, like this:

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 form-change" required="" id="id_quantity">
```

And:

```
<input type="number" name="rate" value="0.0" step="0.01" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 form-change" required="" id="id_rate">
```

And change `$('#form-change').keyup()` to `$('.form-change').keyup()`

Hopefully you could see the console.

OR

Change id of form.

```
<form id="demo-form2 form-change">
```

To:

```
<form id="form-change">
```

Comment: <input type="number" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="" id="id_quantity form-change">

Comment: Please change $('#form-change') to $('.form-change'). The above id is not a valid id. Please change it to class. And revert "id='id_quantity'"

Comment: why the "#form-change'' id is not a valid id? It entered inside the if(quantity && rate) block but did not update the basic_amount value. quantity field is integer field, rate field and basic_amount is decimalfield

Comment: <form id="demo-form2 form-change"> is not valid since you have two values specified. While <form id="form-change"> is valid since only one value is specified in the id attribute(must be unique ). Please check on how to specify id attributes to HTML elements.